# Display paragraph content in list

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to content displaying in single line in list style. I want to display content after comma (,) in new line with the help of pure css.

```css
.datatype {
  color: #3e3a3a;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="datatype">
  <p>Hello Noah, Hello Noah, Hello Liam, Hello Mason, Hello Jacob, Hello William, Hello Ethan, Hello James, Hello Elijah</p>
</div>
```

Content showing like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNrSy.png

Desired Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR14p.png

[Link to jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xvjfhz2y/)

Comment: With only CSS not possible, you'll need to change the HTML as well (or manipulate it via JS). You could a line break (`<br />`) after each comma. Or add an actual line break in the HTML and then add `white-space: pre` to your CSS

Comment: @LinkinTED is this possible with JS. If yes, could you please share code with me?

Comment: look at codeherks's answer, that are the options I gave, but then all worked out... :)

Comment: If you don't want to change the HTML or use JS, you can simple give the `<p>` a fixed width and a wrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

1. use `<p>` tags for each name
2. add `</br>` after each name

   - can be done with **HTML** or **JS**

### Option 1

```css
.datatype{
    color: #3e3a3a;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="datatype">
  <p>Hello Noah,</p>
  <p>Hello Noah,</p> 
  <p>Hello Liam,</p>
  <p>Hello Mason,</p> 
  <p>Hello Jacob,</p> 
  <p>Hello William,</p> 
  <p>Hello Ethan,</p> 
  <p>Hello James,</p> 
  <p>Hello Elijah</p>
 </div>
```

### Option 2 (HTML)

```css
.datatype{
    color: #3e3a3a;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="datatype">
  <p id="names">Hello Noah,</br> Hello Noah,</br> Hello Liam,</br> Hello Mason,</br> Hello Jacob,</br> Hello William,</br> Hello Ethan,</br> Hello James,</br> Hello Elijah</p>
 </div>
```

### Option 2 (JS)

```js
//let list = document.getElementById('names');
let list = document.getElementsByClassName('datatype')[0].querySelector('p');

//console.log(list);
console.log(list.innerHTML);

let arr = list.innerHTML.split(',').map((name) => name.trim() + ',</br>');
console.log(arr);
console.log(arr.join(''));
list.innerHTML = arr.join('');
```

```css
.datatype{
    color: #3e3a3a;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="datatype">
  <p id="names">Hello Noah, Hello Noah, Hello Liam, Hello Mason, Hello Jacob, Hello William, Hello Ethan, Hello James, Hello Elijah</p>
 </div>
```

---

## Edit

Looking at the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xvjfhz2y/) you've included, You can change `document.getElementsByClassName('data')[0].querySelector('p')`
to `document.getElementsByClassName('data')[1].querySelector('p')`.

This will get the second element rather than the first.
You can also give the table row you want to change another **class** name, and replace `'data'` with the name of your new class.

I also see that you using **jQuery**. The equivalent of

`document.getElementsByClassName('data')[1].querySelector('p')` is `$('.data p')[1]`

[LINK TO JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/36t1mkup/2/)

Comment: i only want to use this for specific category not for all the classes. How to set JS to apply only for datatype class not for other classes.

Comment: @James check my edit. the previous version used `getElementById` and in HTML an id name can can only be used **once**. class names can be used more than once. The new edit grabs the first element that has `datatype` as their class name. let me know if you have any questions. If you have any requirements or constraints, please edit your question to reflect that so I or others can answer it in your liking.

Comment: Code is not working on my website. Could you please check full code and make changes?   https://jsfiddle.net/xvjfhz2y/

I only want to make changes in Boys Done section

Comment: @James Look at new edit.. For future questions please be sure to include more details to the question.. The question did not mention that you are using jQuery and it was missing more code for the table.

Comment: @James if the answer solved your problem and it was helpful, be sure to **accept and upvote**

Comment: Code is not working on my website. Anyway thanks for giving time to answer my question. I have already accepted your question as best answer.

Comment: @James you shouldn't have... look at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qentx96k/). I made changes to both **HTML and JS**. Be sure to look at them.

Comment: I can't change **HTML Code** I can only make changes in **css** and **javascript/jquery**. Anyway thanks for your help.